# pip hanging on every command

Tags: python, pip

Every single pip command / package I install, be it in a virtualenv or on system, is hanging.

Running `pip list -v` hangs at this point for 20 seconds:

```
1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
* https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
Getting credentials from keyring for https://pypi.org/simple
Getting credentials from keyring for pypi.org
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
```

Have already upgraded pip, set up a cache, but still have issue. My internet has a little latency but I still have a 50mbs connection.

Any help greatly appreciated.

pip version: 20.3.3
os: ubuntu 18

Comment: if server works slowly then even 100GBs connection will be useless.